# PLEASE HELP, desperate for answers!!! sudden/random clean shutdowns!! :/

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have bought myself a "new" Desktop PC, with Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on it, almost plain without any updates but was used and dont really know what was the previous owner doing, so...Im assuming stuff.

Since the community here is thankfully really filled with professionals too, I AM kindly for help.

So at first, there is NO specific reason that causes a suddenly initiated shutdown, but found out I had around 8x the 41 critical error "Kernel power"- 2 of the 8 were with the BugCheck error code (dec) 50, others 0.

I got that (I assume,since Ive never seen it again) fixed by updating the Realtek audio driver(because for some reason-inet community said-could be caused by that,so...), but then, the chaos started to escalate!-> Blue screen STOP: c000021a {fatal system error}- status 0x00000000 ( 0xc0000001 0x001004b0) apparently its supposed to mean- services are screwed like...WinLogon or CSRSS, eventhough sfc said naah,its fine O.o

YES, I checked all the obvious stuff like memcheck, chkdsk, sfc, so didnt found a bad sector, no corrupt Windows files, nor faulty hardware, voltage(monitored by standard/NOT flashed BIOS) and wattage were fine O.o

then next BSOD after an update done automatically by ***** Uplay saying:

A process or thread crucial to sys operation has unexpectedly exited or been terminated
STOP: 0x000000F4 .....

I...AM...LOST!? Wut should I do? O.o clean wipe HDD then fresh install of win7(or even 8.1), and manually instal drivers while first making a restore point and then step-by-step repeating? O.o

PLEEASE HELP! because I really dont have money to spend on certain easier possibilities.... :/

Specs:

GIGABYTE GA-970A-D3 rev. 1.0 (current primary(because its a dual BIOS) BIOS v F7) amd phenom ii x4 9xx QUAD core 3.00 GHz 10 GB DDR3 2000+ MHz RAM 1TB HDD

I unbelievably appreciate ANY HELP!!! Its just that I trust this community the most + people here are more detailed and kind. Thanks to anyone who is willing to help :/

P.S. : sorry for the lame writing with shorts like upd8...

Comment: My eyes are crying after trying to read that. You're likely to get more help if you edit the question and keep it concise.

Comment: Could you please write this in english rather than in l33t? E.g. "Ultim8" is spelled "Ultimate". "cus" is spelled "because".  "ppl" is spelled "people".  "not to b" is "not to be". "rly" is spelled "really" .... (and many others).

Comment: I agree with the above commenters, you really need to remove all shorthand text (rly, fuqin, ppl, b, any 1, etc) and clearly state what your issue is.   That being said, it could be a lot of things.   I would reccomend downloading BlueScreenView from NirSoft ( http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview_setup.exe ) as it will give you a good idea of what caused the BSOD.

Comment: So should I put BlueScreenView onto a USB Flash drive, and run it via console used by the win7 dvd and its cmd prompt? because as soon as I use ANY tool loaded from the HDD there is for some reason a possible shutdown again, eventhough only windows neccessary drivers were loaded? ...and also doing stuff in Safe mode is also not really as safe as I thought hah...

Comment: @bwDraco - comment removed.  Although I would like to point out, even though some of the problems in this question were address, the user is still begging us to help him, after I kindly explained thats not required.

Answer (score 1):

Try following these instructions in the Microsoft link to perform a clean boot.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331796

If the clean boot did not help, please install this utility

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview_setup.exe

Once you have it open, you will notice it lists your blue screens. If you click on one it will show the modules that were loaded and the faulting modules highlighted in red.

[image: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.gif]

For each module, determine what hardware it belongs to (if it is not a windows module). From there go to the hardware's manufacturers website and download the newest drivers for your device. If you know what device the module belongs to but have no clue who the manufacturer is, find it in windows device manager, click properties, details tab, hardware IDs and get its VEN and DEV codes. From there, use the DEV code on http://pcidatabase.com/
[image]

In my case I did a vendor search because they didnt have my device id (1912)

[image]

Now you can search for drivers because you know who made the hardware.

---

If all of that fails, you have two choices. You can backup all your data to external storage and then format the computer and re-install windows.

Or if you have successfully determined that it's all caused by one thing such as the sound card or the graphics card, replace that piece of hardware.

However it might be more cost effective to first try a format - reinstall if you already have the resources to do that.

Comment: Wow....I am so thankful for this detailed and very time consuming help :O :D
I really greatly appreciate your valuable time that you putted into this, Im gonna try this out immediately :)))

Comment: No worries it only took a couple minutes. I hope you can pinpoint the cause of your issue. If you're getting a BSOD right when you open a program, that might actually be faulty RAM. But I thought you did a test of it? Anyways definitely try to reinstall windows if that is available to you. Just make sure to backup all your data to that USB Flash Drive you say you have. (documents pictures, favourites etc).

You should probably first try to reinstall windows without formatting incase the computer has drivers that will be difficult to acquire. If that fails, do a format - reinstall.

Comment: Ok so...Im in trouble :///

during a memtest86, the pc JUST turnd off as if power was gone O.o

Then 5mins. afterwards (eventhough in BIOS config under AC power back it is set to NOT turn back on) the PC suddenly unexpected completely turns him self on?! O.o

I am so weirded out honestly...faulty PSU? Or...I dont know :///

Comment: Are you sure it was 5 minutes? I have a gigabyte too. I think I remember that when I changed around frequencies or misconfigured them, the bios shuts the computer down, then turns it back on 10 seconds later. Maybe some frequency is unstable. Have you tried going in the BIOS and restoring the default settings? I think it's called default settings or fail-safe values or something.

Comment: Quickly, backup your data off that hard drive incase the PSU is sending incorrect voltages just incase something gets fried. Now download hwmonitor and take a screenshot of the voltages or something.

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

Also note the temperatures, anything overheating like the cpu. Maybe a screenshot of voltages and temperatures.

Comment: Okay so,BlueScreenViewer tells me only 1 thing- ntoskrnl.exe is malfunctioning or how I should say that... I didnt try the BIOS possibilities yet,but yesterday Ive seen another topic where a guy had the exactly same thing as me except his time was 30mins +/- almost constantly until it initiated a random shutdown. His thought was faulty mainboard,so I assume he exchanged it and solved it. But,jeez is that model really so well-known for bein faulty? O.o

Comment: Update- I have done the fail-safe bios configs buut...it just went worse O.o After all this weird stuff happening, I am actually also frightened-should I risk a HDD clean slate/wipe and reformating using DiskPart or...? O.o I rly am genuinely lost....

Comment: Do you have a valid retail version of windows? (If you dont have the original cd that came with this computer, and reinstall using an OEM CD, windows will fail to activate successfully and nag you about being not genuine possibly a victim of software counterfeiting.)

if your computer has multiple sticks of RAM, you can try removing all sticks but one. (preferably keeping whichever you think is less cheap) and follow up by trying out each stick one by one, switching if one causes a crash to figure out if maybe one or more of the RAM sticks are bad.